# css default if inherit not defined

Tags: css

Is it possible to set a default value for css property if inherit is not defined?
For example:

```
.td { 
    font-size: 9px; 
}
.link { 
    font-size: inherit; 
    color: inherit; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

On

```
<td class=td>
    <a class=link href="#">hello!!</a>
 </td>
```

the `<a>` inherit font-size from .td.

However, on

```
<td>
    <a class=link href="#">hello!!</a>
</td>
```

the `<a>` tag has no font-size attribute.

Comment: If it's not defined it probably will be inherited unless the cascade determines otherwise....but not everything is inherited.  It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: using the given example, I want a .link css the applies the same font-size as the parent td, but if the parent td has no class, then I would like to define a default style.

Comment: You can just define `.link` with a font size and `td .link` with another, which will only change the size when its in an td, otherwise it will use the default. It comes down specificity: `.link` is less specific than `td .link`, so `td .link` will be preferred over `.link` when its nested inside a `td`.

Answer (score 0):

It comers down to `specificity` - the more specific, the more preference the rule gets. So you can simply define a global, and then modify it locally. If the rule does not match, it does not get overwritten. Heres a snippet example:

```css
body { font-size: 20px; }
div { font-size: 10px; }
```

```html
<div><a href="#">Nested inside a div</a></div>

<a href="#">Not nested</a>
```

`div` is not *more* specific but gets preference because it is defined later. Just make sure that you don;t define the default font-size for a link and it will always inherit it from the closest valid rule. If you do want to set a font-size, you will have to add it to your class description like this:

```
div, div a { font-size: 10px; }
```

Comment: Is it possible to set some kind of selector that indicates that parent hasn't font-size attribute, in order to use a more generic style sheet? td{no font-size} > .link { font-size: 9px; }

Comment: @fcaserio No, theres isnt. You will have to do with cascading!

Comment: Ok, using a { font-size: 7pt; } to set the default solves the question. Sometimes the simplest solution is at hand and we dont realize. tks 4 helping